# minimal value of Binary Tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I am trying to define a minTree function using foldTree define by:

```
foldTree :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f e Leaf         = e
foldTree f e (Node left x right) = f (foldTree f e left) x (foldTree f e right)
```

Here what I have so far.

```
minTree :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> Maybe a
minTree f e Leaf = e
minTree tree = foldTree f e tree
             where
             f x nothing  = Just x
             f x (Just y) = Just (min x y)
             e            = Nothing
```

But this code does not work and give a some error that I don't understand how to fix. Can someone help me to figure out what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: `nothing` is a variable like `z`. You probably meant `Nothing`. Keep warnings enabled to make GHC spot these kinds of mistakes. Also, `f` must take 3 arguments to be used in `foldTree`. Finally, always post the error! By not posting the error you are forcing us to guess it, making our answers less precise.

Comment: the number of parameters to `minTree` in the definition does not conform to the number of parameters in the signature, in the second line.

Comment: `foldTree` is basically the definition of `foldr` in the instance of `Foldable` you'd need to just use the predefined `minimum` function.

Comment: (Though `minTree` would still have to handle an empty tree separately before passing non-empty trees off to `minimum`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `b ~ Maybe a`. This thus means that the first and the third parameter of `f` are `Maybe a`s. You thus will need to check both. The second item is an `a`. Your `f` should thus determine the minimum of two `Maybe a`s and an `a`, so something like:

```
minTree :: Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe a
minTree tree = foldTree f Nothing tree
    where f Nothing y Nothing = Just y
          f Nothing y (Just z) = …
          f (Just x) y Nothing = …
          f (Just x) y (Just z) = …
```

where I leave implementing the `…` parts as an exercise. Since `a` is a member of the `Ord` typeclass, you can work with [**`min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:min).